# How to upload large amounts of data from MsSQL datatable to MySQL datatable, daily fast?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database, etl, data-migration

I need upload cca 770_000 datarow every day from one MsSQL datatable to another MySQL datatable.
I wrote a short program, that deletes in the first step the MySQL datatable, than loops through the MsSQL recordset, and inserts every row step by step into the MySQL table.

But for this amount of data, it takes a very long time...

Do you have any tip for speeds up this task, or any other solution?

Comment: You should use batch insertion for this which will reduce execution time.

Answer (score 1):

This task is generically known as Extract-Transform-Load. [etl](/questions/tagged/etl).
You didn't give us many details. So it's hard to give a specific answer.

Your best bet for a clean workflow is to read the table from your source server (SQL Server in your case) and write out a [.csv file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values). If you can find a fully-debugged tool or library to write the .csv file that's best: writing correct .csv files is, notoriously, much harder than it looks.  It's possible you can configure SSIS to do this part of your task for you.

You can then use MySQL's [LOAD DATA INFILE command](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html) to read that csv file. That command is built for your purpose, and is astonishingly fast.

And, by the way, don't drop and recreate the table before loading it. [TRUNCATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/truncate-table.html) it instead. That tells the database server you want to use the same table definition with new data.

If you *must* process your data row-by-row in a program for some reason, the trick to fast INSERTing of multiple rows is this: do the inserts in transaction batches of about 100 rows each.  Two ways to do that:

1. Write your INSERT statements like this, with about 100 rows per statement.

   ```sql
   INSERT INTO tbl (col1, col2, col3) VALUES
   (1,2,3),
   (4,5,6),
   (7,8,9);
   ```
2. Use [explicit transactions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/commit.html), in which you wrap each batch of about 100 INSERT statements in `START TRANSACTION` and `COMMIT`. Something like this

   ```sql
   START TRANSACTION;
   INSERT INTO tbl (col1, col2, col3) VALUES (1,2,3);
   INSERT INTO tbl (col1, col2, col3) VALUES (4,5,6);
   INSERT INTO tbl (col1, col2, col3) VALUES (7,8,9);
   COMMIT;
   ```

There are ETL software packages on the market. But many of them have far too many features and are hard to use.

Answer (score 0):

1. Dump from MSSql to a comma- or tab-separated file.
2. (On MySQL) `CREATE TABLE t (...);`
3. `LOAD DATA INFILE INTO t ...`  -- not impacting the 'real' table
4. `RENAME TABLE real TO old, t TO real;`  -- atomic and fast
5. `DUMP TABLE old;`  -- clean up

That technique will

- Perform the task at maximal speed.
- Have no time when the table is missing on MySQL.  (Better than `TRUNCATE`.)